# Splitting polygons with at most ${3n\over 4}$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, computational-geometry, coloring

Given a simple polygon of $n$ vertices, and $n$ sufficiently large, prove
that there exists a diagonal that splits the polygon into two polygons, each with at most ${3n\over 4}$ vertices?

So I know this:

It's a direct relation of the 4 color theorem. Take a planar graph `G`, and color it in 4 colors. All vertices except the ones in the color class of greatest size form a vertex cover consisting of at most `3*V(G)/4` vertices.

It's `3/4*n` because we are working with triangulation.

So my question is this: What else do I need to prove this by induction? And where would you start to prove this?

Comment: Must say I don't understand this problem. It is easy to draw a diagonal so that it splits polygon on two parts each with $\leq n/2$ points.

Comment: @ChristianF I assume that the polygon is allowed to be concave, in which case arbitrary diagonals cannot be drawn.

Comment: This is the only information I have... The stuff that so I know this: is what I am thinking.

Comment: Well, if they're convex polygons, the problem is trivial, and there doesn't seem to be any need to involve graph theory; that's why people are confused. If you draw a diagonal between any two vertices, the total number of vertices of the two polygons you make is $n+2$ (the endpoints of the diagonal are counted twice). So, you can make each have at most $\lceil\frac{n+2}{2}\rceil \leq \frac{n+3}{2}$ vertices, and $\frac{n+3}{2} \leq \frac{3n}{4}$ if $n \geq 6$.